# TypeError: unbound method loadDisplacement() must be called with person instance as first argument (got float64 instance instead)

Tags: list, typeerror

This is the code I have written so far:
I am very new to python so am trying to use the most basic ways of accomplishing goals as possible as I currently don't know how to make it more efficient etc.

```
def simulateBeamRun(personlist, beam, times):
    times = np.linspace(0,35,500)
    templist = []
    maxdeflectionlist = []
    for t in times:
        for i in personlist: #for each person instance
            Tuple = personModel.person.loadDisplacement(t)
            if 0 < Tuple(1) < beamModel.beam.L:
                templist.append(Tuple)
            else:
                pass
    return templist
```

File "beamSimulation.py", line 40, in simulateBeamRun
    Tuple = personModel.person.loadDisplacement(t)

The error I am getting is:

```
TypeError: unbound method loadDisplacement() must be called with person instance as first argument (got float64 instance instead)
```

personlist is a list of lists each containing arrivalTime, weight, gait, speed for a given "person". This is so that it gives values to the constructor. Load displacement is the only other function in the person class:

```
class person(object):
    """This class models the displacement of a person's load as they run at 
    'speed' in one dimension. It assumes that the load is always concentrated 
    in a single point and that the displacement of that point is less than or 
    equal to the displacement of the person's centre of mass. Also the 
    displacement of the load will always be a multiple of 'gait'.
    """
    def __init__(self, arrivalTime, weight, gait, speed):
        """This constructor function defines the person's weight, gait and 
        running speed as well as the time that they arrive at the position of 
        zero displacement.
        """
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited code presented, some of this is just guessing, but it might point you in the right direction, at least:

1. There's no need to pass in the `times` argument if you're just going to immediately overwrite it with `times = ...`.
2. You're not using `maxdeflectionlist` for anything, so it's not really needed (although maybe you're planning to later...).
3. Inside your `for i in ...` loop, `i` is your iteration variable, and should take each value successively from `personlist`. Guessing from variable names, these might be the `person` instances that you need to get displacements from, so the line that you're getting the error on should maybe be `Tuple = i.loadDisplacement(t)`. If that's not the case, given your later comments, perhaps you need to instantiate a `person` object from the data in `i` - something like `p = personModel.person(some, arguments, extracted, from, i)`, and then follow that with `Tuple = p.loadDisplacement(t)`. Calling `loadDisplacement()` as you have is more appropriate for a class method or static method, not for an instance method, which is the essential meaning behind the error message you get. It's telling you that `personModel.person` is not a `person` instance - it's probably a class object.
4. The `else: pass` bit is sort of pointless.